# Date Difference in Android

Tags: java, date

I have two String date 8-11-2011 and 8-12-2011 . I want to compute days between two string . How can I do that ? I don't want to use Joda API . Please explain with example .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838527/android-java-date-difference-in-days

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have any direct api for this but you can do this,

```
String s1 = "8-11-2011";
String s2 = "8-12-2011";

String[] arr1 = s1.split("-");
String[] arr2 = s2.split("-");
for(int i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
Integer diff = Integer.valuof(arr1[i])-Integer.valueOf(arr2[i])// its just an idea. you may need if conditions here
}
```

and its not reliable..

Comment: We have the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes now, so need to bother with this kind of roll-your-own approach. For early Android, see [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this for the problem [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897027/getting-difference-between-two-dates-android/16830015#16830015)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: ok. :) but may i know if stackoverflow linked pages may ever become invalid?

Comment: Mark this Question as a duplicate rather than link to an Answer.