# How to show the date difference in days?

Tags: android, date

I need to get the actual date and minus the date from the value in the database, the date now is `now` and the date in the database is `this.vencimento`.

```
  public boolean getDiasVencido() {
    boolean diasvencido = false;                

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date datahora = null;       
    try {
        datahora = (Date) formatter.parse(this.vencimento);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date now = new Date();      
    if(datahora.compareTo(now) < 0 ) { 


        long diff = "DATE NOW - DATE FROM DATABASE (this.vencimento)";
        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        diasvencido = true; 

    }
    return diasvencido;
}
```

the variables setted in the class:

```
     public class classetitulo {

private String documento;
private String vencimento;
private Double valor;
private Double multa;
private Double juros;

public classetitulo() {}

public classetitulo(String documento, String vencimento, Double valor, Double multa, Double juros) {
    this.documento = documento;
    this.vencimento = vencimento;
    this.valor = valor;
    this.juros = juros;
    this.multa = multa;
}
```

I don't know much how to do it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not query it with an SQL statement like `DATEDIFF`

Comment: how? can you show me an example of it?

Comment: Alright, whats the exactly SQLite statement?

Comment: please refer to this problem's [solution][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897027/getting-difference-between-two-dates-android/16830015#16830015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`this.diasvencido = Integer.parseInt(""+(((now.getTime() - datahora.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))));`

It will get the date in time and it will times by the day giving the result to Days.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. This is how to calculate how many days have passed until now:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
     long dataHora = formatter.parse(this.vencimento).getTime();
     long duration = Math.abs(now - dataHora);
     long diff = duration / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
}
catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The class [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) is available since API Level 3, but you can always calculate the value of `DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS` by yourself.