# Get Relative Time for Future Date

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-calendar, java-calendar

The below code will output `Yesterday`, `X Minutes ago`, etc. from past.

`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timeInMilliSeconds);`

How to reverse it for future? Like `Tomorrow`, `After X Minutes`, `After X Hours`, `After 2 Days` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting difference between two dates Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897027/getting-difference-between-two-dates-android) and other similar questions. Please search to find more.